# Replace (null) with '0' globally, dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

The project i have inherited has a lot of variables that take string values. Their sole purpose is to help in checking whether something is true or false. The values that are assigned throughout the program to these variables are:

- `(null)`
- `0`
- `any integer value > 0`
- `true`
- `false`

Is there a simple way to make sure, whenever a `(null)` is being assigned to them, it automatically gets assigned a `0` or `FALSE` instead.

That way `if(...)` conditions would be much easier to handle.

Comment: Understand that `nil`, `null`, `NULL`, and `FALSE` are all zero.  The only one you really need to watch out for is an NSNull object, which will not compare `==` to `nil`.  Different schemes may use different "true" values -- `1` is most common, but a word of all binary 1s is also used in some contexts (though rarely in C-based languages).  So to compare for "true" is usually safest to compare for `!= 0`, `!= FALSE`, or simply (a little weird) `!!theBoolVar`.  You really just have to watch out for the NSNull case, and any schemes that maybe return -1 for "failure", etc.

Comment: @HotLicks: Why don't you write an answer instead?

Comment: @DarkDust - I'm too lazy to page down that far.

Comment: NSNull it is.
I am using if ((id)[NSNull null]==...) for the comparisons.

Comment: And null is not same as zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let's explain something about 0/null/nil:

A variable that points to an Objective-C object can point to "nothing". There is a special value for this, `nil`. That magic value `nil` is equivalent to the number 0 (which is interpreted as a memory location 0 in this case). The values `NO` and `false` are also mapped to 0, so `0 == nil == NULL == NO == false` (not exactly, but for most cases you can make this assumption).

So you can check whether a string variable points to "nothing" by checking for `nil`:

```
if (myString == nil) ... // (1)
if (!myString) ... // (1.1), this is equivalent to (1) but implicit
```

But you usually also want *empty strings* (`@""`) to also be considered as being "nothing". You can now do this:

```
if (myString == nil || [myString length] == 0) ... // (2)
```

We can use a special property of Objective-C to make this even shorter: if you call a method on `nil` it behaves like an object that returns 0 to everything. So we don't need to check for `nil` in this case:

```
if ([myString length] == 0) ... // (3), this is equivalent to (2)
```

Now, if you have magic string values like `@"FALSE"` that you want to test for, I recommend you create a category on NSString and add a method that combines these tests:

```
@interface NSString (MyMagicValues)
- (BOOL)isTrue;
@end
@implementation NSString (MyMagicValues)
- (BOOL)isTrue
{
   // No need to test "self == nil" here, that cannot happen.
   if ([self length] == 0) return NO;
   if ([self isEqualToString:@"FALSE"]) return NO;
   if ([self isEqualToString:@"0") return NO;
   return YES
}
@end
```

The trick here is to remember that calling this on `nil` will return 0/NO, so the default value should also be NO. Now you can do:

```
if (![myString isTrue]) ... // (4)
```

This variant will be true if `myString` is:

- `nil`
- empty string
- `@"FALSE"`
- `@"0"`

(BTW, you usually get the `(null)` when you do something like `NSLog(@"%@", nil);`. Do not test whether the variable is `[NSNull null]` except in very, *very* rare cases where you know what you're doing as it it's usually pointless.)

Your question was really whether you can make Objective-C assign a special value to a string variable whenever `(null)` is assigned. You cannot do that, which might be obvious already: the `(null)` is what `NSLog` gives you when you print "nothing" (`nil`), that is if "nothing" has been assigned to your variable. You will need to modify your `if` statements accordingly, using a method on NSString as I've just described is the best way to handle this (especially if there are various magic values like `@"0"`, `@"false" or whatever can occur).

**Edit:** You've clarified that you want to check for `[NSNull null]`. You can now do something like:

```
if (myString == (id)[NSNull null] || [myString length] == 0) ... // (5), check for NSNull first!
```

or if you have magic string values and want to go the category way:

```
if (myString == (id)[NSNull null] || ![myString isTrue]) ... // (6)
```

If you want to go the category way you can now also add an `isTrue` to NSNull like this:

```
@interface NSNull (MyMagicValues)
- (BOOL)isTrue;
@end
@implementation NSNull (MyMagicValues)
- (BOOL)isTrue
{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Now both `NSString` and `NSNull` have an `isTrue` and you can again do the simple check *(4)* again: `if (![myString isTrue]) ...`. Depending on the code size and complexity, adding these two categories might be a bit ugly… or might considerably improve your code. It's up to you to decide that.

Comment: Setting (null) to 0 globally was conflicting with other variables i had not taken into account.
I eventually altered my code to assign only 0s and 1s to these strings. Makes things easier.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is caused by using JSON, I developed a solution used in a shipping app that worked great.

What I did was create a category on `NSNull` and depending on what message I got returned the appropriate value. For instance, in the category (no code handy, this from memory):

```
-(int)intvalue { return 0; }
-(BOOL) boolValue { return NO; }
-(NSString *)description { return @""; }
-(NSInteger)integerValue { return 0; }
-(float)floatValue { return 0.0f; }
```

In my processing code, where I deal with the `ObjectiveC` objects returned from `JSON` conversion, I tended to always use integerValue, since it works with both `NSString`, `NSNumber`, and my `NSNull` category.

Answer (score -1):

first define

```
#define STRING_IS_EMPTY_OR_NIL( _STRING ) ( _STRING == nil || [str isEqualToString:@""] )


NSString *str=@"your string";//may be null

if (STRING_IS_EMPTY_OR_NIL(str)) {
    NSLog(@"Null");
     str=@"0";

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"not Null");
}
```

Comment: `nil` == `NULL` for all practical purposes. And despite the name, you're not checking whether a string is empty.

Comment: yes...u can write like  #define STRING_IS_EMPTY_OR_NIL( _STRING ) ( _STRING == nil || [_STRING isEqualToString:@""] )

Answer (score -1):

Use below:

```
if (string == nil)
   string = @"0";
```